# wxString to UniChar*

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets, unichar, wxstring

How to convert from wxString to UniChar?

Answer (score 2):

You have to check the wxMBConv classes.

The base class for all these conversions is the wxMBConv class (which itself implements standard libc locale conversion). Derived classes include wxMBConvLibc, several different wxMBConvUTFxxx classes, and wxCSConv, which implement different kinds of conversions. You can also derive your own class for your own custom encoding and use it, should you need it. All you need to do is override the MB2WC and WC2MB methods.

Several of the wxWidgets-provided wxMBConv classes have predefined instances (wxConvLibc, wxConvFileName, wxConvUTF7, wxConvUTF8, wxConvLocal). You can use these predefined objects directly, or you can instantiate your own objects.

A variable, wxConvCurrent, points to the conversion object that the user interface is supposed to use, in the case that the user interface is not Unicode-based (like with GTK+ 1.2). By default, it points to wxConvLibc or wxConvLocal, depending on which works best on the current platform.

The wxCSConv class is special because when it is instantiated, you can tell it which character set it should use, which makes it meaningful to keep many instances of them around, each with a different character set (or you can create a wxCSConv instance on the fly).

The predefined wxCSConv instance, wxConvLocal, is preset to use the default user character set, but you should rarely need to use it directly, it is better to go through wxConvCurrent.